# removing layout parameter programmatically

Tags: android

I am using the following code to set the parameters of a layout programatically

```
LinearLayout text;
text = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)text.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

I am guessing that this sets the alignParentRight vale to true. Is it possible for me to programmatically set this value to false as well if I need to?

Comment: Just pass `0` as a second parameter for the `addRule` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by Luksprog, `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);` sets the value to false.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to remove layout parameters since API level 17 with:

```
public void removeRule (int verb)
```

Details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29).

Comment: That method is only available when using 4.2.